# ansible script module: what is `cmd` for?

Tags: ansible

I'm just reading the [`script` module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/script_module.html), and I don't understand what the `cmd` property is good for. The documentation states that `script`:

> The script module takes the script name followed by a list of space-delimited arguments.

Where `cmd` also takes a script followed by a list of arguments.

Can someone explain the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a formatting option.  The following two tasks are functionally identical:

```
- name: Run a script with arguments (using 'cmd' parameter)
  script:
    cmd: /some/local/script.sh --some-argument 1234

- name: Run a script with arguments (freeform)
  script: /some/local/create_file.sh --some-argument 1234
```